# How to include the xsd:documentation in the C# class generated with XSD.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, documentation, xsd, xml-documentation

I am using [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28VS.71%29.aspx) to generate a C# class from a collection of xsd files.  The xsd file makes use of the `<xsd:documentation>` tag to include useful descriptions.  Example:

```
<xsd:complexType name="AddressType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>A formatted or free form address and its intended use.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
```

Unfortunately all of this is lost in the generated C# class.  Interestingly each class has an empty **remarks** documentation tag attached to it.

```
/// <remarks/>
```

How can I include this documentation in the generated C# class (either in  or  documentation tags)?

Comment: This would be a useful feature to have this XSD.exe to generate the Summary on the objects based on the XSD <xs:annotation> / <xs:documentation>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xsd.exe is based on Codedom.

You could disassemble xsd.exe, and add the functionality there and recompile. 
The code is reasonably simple.

I had modified it to skip some namespaces from xsd while generating code.[Otherwise If I include a common.xsd in 2 other xsds the class was getting generated twice.]

Granted, I had access to source proper itself [I was a developer at Microsoft], but the process should be simple with diassembled code as well.

Comment: And why Microsoft does not share this code? Other programmers will fix xsd.exe code and improve it for all for free.